# Need a htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to redirect following URL `http://bla.bleh.com/?node_id=123&uid=456` to `http://bla.bleh.com/yeah/baby/?node_id=123&uid=456`

and tried many things yet like:

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ^node_id=123&uid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule     ^/\?node_id=142&uid=([0-9]+)$ /yeah/baby/?node_id=123&uid=$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ^node_id=123&uid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule     ^/\?node_id=142&uid=([0-9]+)$ /yeah/baby/?node_id=123&uid=%1 [L,R=301]
```

and I'm pretty much stucked. Anybody an idea for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the RewriteRule operate on the Path only (not comprising the query string),

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ^node_id=123&uid=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule     ^/?$ /yeah/baby/?node_id=123&uid=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yeah thank you. I already tried this solution but had another issue with the website so that it did not work on first try.